# Autocomplete - Using CakePHP 1.3 + jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, autocomplete

I was following this [tutorial](http://blogfreakz.com/cakephp/cakephp-jquery-autocomplete-tutorial) (for CakePHP 1.3)

The autocomplete works and the data that gets returned via JSON looks correct:

```
[{"value":"test2","label":"<img class=\"avatar\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\" src=\"test2.jpg\"><span class=\"username\">test2<\/span>"},{"value":"test","label":"<img class=\"avatar\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\" src=\"test.jpg\"><span class=\"username\">test<\/span>"}]
```

The dropdown the gets populated as expected, but the returned items are not formatted correctly:

```
&lt;img class="avatar" width="24" height="24" src="test2.jpg"&gt;&lt;span class="username"&gt;test2&lt;/span&gt;
```

Expected Result:

```
<img class="avatar" width="24" height="24" src="test2.jpg"><span class="username">test</span>
```

Any advice?

Comment: use `html_entity_decode()` to decode the string return. is it right?